# MVC: Is there a way to know, from the view, the sent variables from the controller?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I was wondering if there's a way to know all the variables sent to the view without checking the controller

(maybe something similar to var_dump but for the current scope?)

I am a front end developer and sometimes I don't even understand what the controller is doing but i would like to know what gets to the view.

I believe this is very framework dependent so, lets say, codeigniter?

Thanks

Comment: That all depends how the variables are set. Possibly you are looking for `get_defined_vars()` or `get_object_vars()`

Comment: Might depend on MVC you are using, but I have had the same thought!

Comment: Completely depends on the framework/set-up you’re using. There’s no framework-agnostic answer for this.

Comment: In my case, it's codeigniter

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7218063/how-to-get-all-the-variables-available-in-a-view-in-php

Comment: @We0 MVC is design-pattern and exists only one.

Comment: With the framework I've developed http://use.jackrabbitmvc.com by default the *only* variables available to the view are a) the ones sent by the controller, in an associative array named $model and b) session variables -- I intentionally clobber all other global variables so you cannot use them from the view, but the controller can provide them to the view before they get clobbered.  If you don't like this behavior, you can extend LeakyJackRabbitMto (MTO stands for "model transfer object"), but do you really want to work with an abstraction with "Leaky" in its name?

Comment: Where is the MVC in the framework @GeorgeJempty? Contrary to popular believe MVC is not just a marketing term you can put on any code you write :-)

Comment: @PeeHaa Instead of being snarky why don't you try explaining why you don't think it conforms to MVC?  Because it doesn't have an ORM layer?  Well, who says the model equates to database data, but if it does for you, you are free to use *any* ORM framework you care to, not one that my framework prescribes.  In that way my framework is non-opinionated, and with methods such as 'applyRequestToModel' and 'applyModelToView' I would argue that it's the very essence of MVC.